# Custom resolution for android emulator on virtual box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I've developed an Android application but when I try to run it in the emulator via Eclipse, the emulator always takes a LONG time to load. I've decided to create an Android virtual machine on VirtualBox, I've installed `AndroBOX-2.3.r.1-generic`, it works fine and faster, but when I try to run my app, I have a `RuntimeException: unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class GridLayout`.

I hope that the problem could be solved if I run the Android virtual machine with a custom resolution. I have developed my app for a 10.1' WXGA800 tablet (Theme.Holo). How can I find the useful resolution data to edit the .vbox configuration file?

```xml
<ExtraData>
   <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="?"/>
   <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="?,?"/>
   <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="?,?,?,?"/>
   <ExtraDataItem name="CustomVideoMode1" value="?x?x?"/> 
</ExtraData>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have problems running the app on your tablet ? or is this issue occurs on all devices?

Comment: Actually, I haven't a physical device I can use to run my app. I developed and tested it using Eclipse + SDK. My app works just fine, but the default Android emulator is far too slow for accurate testing. So I've decided to setting up a faster Android emulator on a Linux VirtualBox, but I have that exception caused by layout.

Comment: It seems the problem was the adb.exe process... I have tried to terminate Eclipse, the virtual machine, the adb process for several times, and finally my app is running now.

However, I can't figure out how to change the screen resolution and dimension of the Android emulator on the Virtual Box. In the Eclipse graphical layout, I have modelled my app for a 10.1' WXGA tablet. When I try to run it the entire screen is not visible. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding your resolution changing question:

You need to configure your desired resolution in two places:

**In the VirtualBox virtual machine configuration**

1. Shutdown the VM and VirtualBox.
2. Use VBoxManage to configure a custom resolution: `VBoxManage setextradata "YourVMName" "CustomVideoMode1" "480x800x16"` (or any other resolution).

**In the VM Grub Configuration**

1. Remonut the boot partition: `mount -o remount,rw /mnt`
2. Then, you can edit the `menu.lst` file: `vi /mnt/grub/menu.lst`
3. Default parameters are: `quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=eeepc acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode DPI=240 SRC=/android-2.3-RC1`
4. add `UVESA_MODE=480x800` to the parameter line, like so: `quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot_hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode DPI=240`**`UVESA_MODE=480x800`**`SRC=/android-2.3-RC1`

Reboot your machine, it should now boot with the custom resolution you defined.

Comment: If the screen looks all messed up try to use `480x800x32` for example instead.